# What libraries exist for multitenant/conditional configurations for Java?

Tags: java, configuration, velocity, apache-commons-config

I'm trying to find a solution for configuring a server-side Java application such that different users of the system interact with the system as if it were configured differently ([Multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)). For example, when my application services a request from user1, I wish my application to respond in Klingon, but for all other users I want it to reply in English. (I've picked a deliberately absurd example, to avoid specifics: the important thing is that I want the app to behave differently for different requests).

Ideally there's a generic solution (i.e. one that allows me to add 
user-specific overrides to *any* part of my config without having to change code).

I've had a look at Apache Commons Configuration which has [built in support for multitenant configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_multitenant.html), but as far as I can tell this is done by combining *some base config* with *some set of overrides*. This means that I'd have a config specifying:

```
application.lang=english
```

and, say a `user1.properties` override file:

```
application.lang=klingon
```

Unfortunately it's much easier for our support team if they can see all related configurations in one place, with overrides specified somehow inline, rather than having separate files for *base* vs. *overrides*.

I think some combination of Commons Config's multitenancy + something like a [Velocity template](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/index.html) to describe the conditional elements within underlying config is kind of what I'm aiming for - Commons Config for the ease of interacting with my configuration and Velocity for very expressively describing any overrides, in a single configuration, e.g.:

```
#if ($user=="user1")
 application.lang=klingon
#else
 application.lang=english
#end
```

**What solutions are people using for this kind of problem?**

Comment: IMO your velocity example would be much harder to deal with. In general people use an app/front-end for editing multiple config files, like with resource/translation files. Expend only minor amount of energy on a config tool and the back end doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Dave But I'd still need something like this to write the _tool_, if I chose to use this as my back end?

Answer (score 3):

Is it acceptable for you to code each server operation like in the following?

```
void op1(String username, ...)
{
    String userScope = getConfigurationScopeForUser(username);
    String language = cfg.lookupString(userScope, "language");
    int    fontSize = cfg.lookupInt(userScope, "font_size");
    ... // business logic expressed in terms of language and fontSize
}
```

(The above pseudocode assumes the name of a user is passed as a parameter, but you might pass it via another mechanism, for example, thread-local storage.)

If the above is acceptable, then [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) could satisfy your requirements. Using Config4*, the `getConfigurationScopeForUser()` method used in the above pseudocode can be implemented as follows (this assumes `cfg` is a Configuration object that has been previously initialized by parsing a configuration file):

```
String getConfigurationScopeForUser(String username)
{
    if (cfg.type("user", username) == Configuration.CFG_SCOPE) {
        return Configuration.mergeNames("user", username);
    } else {
        return "user.default";
    }

}
```

Here is a sample configuration file to work with the above. Most users get their configuration from the "user.default" scope, but Mary and John have their own overrides of some of those default values:

```
user.default {
    language = "English";
    font_size = "12";
    # ... many other configuration settings
}

user.John {
    @copyFrom "user.default";
    language = "Klingon"; # override a default value
}

user.Mary {
    @copyFrom "user.default";
    font_size = "18"; # override a default value
}
```

If the above sounds like it might meet your needs, then I suggest you read Chapters 2 and 3 of the "Getting Started Guide" to get a good-enough understanding of the Config4* syntax and API to be able to confirm/refute the suitability of Config4* for your needs. You can find that documentation on the Config4* [website](http://www.config4star.org/).

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Config4*.

**Edit: I am providing more details in response to comments by bacar.**

I have not put Config4* in a Maven repository. However, it is trivial to build Config4* with its bundled Ant build file, because Config4* does *not* have any dependencies on third-party libraries.

Another approach for using Config4* in a server application (prompted by a comment by bacar) with Config4* is follows...

Implement each server operation like in the following pseudo-code:

```
void op1(String username, ...)
{
    Configuration cfg = getConfigurationForUser(username);
    String language = cfg.lookupString("settings", "language");
    int    fontSize = cfg.lookupInt("settings", "font_size");
    ... // business logic expressed in terms of language and fontSize
}
```

The `getConfigurationForUser()` method used above can be implemented as shown in the following pseudocode:

```
HashMap<String,Configuration>  map = new HashMap<String,Configuration>();

synchronized String getConfigurationForUser(String username)
{
    Configuration cfg = map.get(username);
    if (cfg == null) {
        // Create a config object tailored for the user & add to the map
        cfg = Configuration.create();
        cfg.insertString("", "user", username); // in global scope
        cfg.parse("/path/to/file.cfg");
        map.put(username, cfg);
    }
    return cfg;    
}
```

Here is a sample configuration file to work with the above.

```
user ?= ""; // will be set via insertString()
settings {
    @if (user @in ["John", "Sam", "Jane"]) {
        language = "Klingon";
    } @else {
        language = "English";
    }
    @if (user == "Mary") {
        font_size = "12";
    } @else {
        font_size = "10";
    }
    ... # many other configuration settings
}
```

The main comments I have on the two approaches are as follows:

1. The first approach (one `Configuration` object that contains lots of variables and scopes) is likely to use slightly less memory than the second approach (many `Configuration` objects, each with a small number of variables). But my guess is that the memory usage of either approach will be measured in KB or tens of KB, and this will be insignificant compared to the overall memory footprint of your server application.
2. I prefer the first approach because a single `Configuration` object is initialized just once, and then it is accessed via read-only `lookup()`-style operations. This means you don't have to worry about synchronizing access to the `Configuration` object, even if your server application is multi-threaded. In contrast, the second approach requires you to synchronize access to the `HashMap` if your server application is multi-threaded.
3. The overhead of a `lookup()`-style operation is in the order of, say, nanoseconds or microseconds, while the overhead of parsing a configuration file is in the order of, say, milliseconds or tens of milliseconds (depending on the size of the file). The first approach performs that relatively expensive parsing of a configuration file only once, and that is done in the initialization of the application. In contrast, the second approach performs that relatively expensive parsing of a configuration file "N" times (once for each of "N" users), and that repeated expense occurs while the server is processing requests from clients. That performance hit may or may not be an issue for your application.
4. I think ease of use is more important than ease of implementation. So, if you feel that the second approach will make it easier to maintain the configuration file, then I suggest you use that approach.
5. In the second approach, you may wonder why I put most of the variables in a named scope (`settings`) rather than in the global scope along with the "injected" `user` variable. I did that for a reason that is outside the scope of your question: separating the "injected" variables from the application-visible variables makes it easier to perform schema validation on the application-visible variables.

Comment: Cool, thanks. +1 for the detailed answer. I came across Config4* on one of your other posts - I wasn't quite sure how to get this to work though. I'm not convinced that I get the expressiveness that a velocity template would give me (e.g. If I want to change just one sub element in some much larger structure) but I'll have a play. Is there a maven repo with config4*?

Comment: Having looked into it a bit, it strikes me that injecting a variable called 'user' (e.g. `cfg.insertString("user", "John")`) then using `@if (user=="John") { language = "Klingon"; } @else { language = "English"; }` might be even easier to manage & get the expressiveness I'm after. @Ciaran - any views on following that approach?

Comment: @bacar: I have edited my answer in response to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Normally user profiles are going into a DB and the user must open a session with a login. The user name may go into the HTTPSession (=Cookies) and on every request the server will get the user name and may read the profile from the DB. Shure, the DB can be some config files like joe.properties, jim.properties, admin.properties, etc.

Comment: It's not an HTTP server application - and this answer doesn't really address the concept of overriding defaults based on conditional logic - you just seem to propose just loading a completely separate properties file.